# Trying to render R4DS to pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tidyverse, knitr

When I try to render the latest version of the book *R for Data Science* (R4DS), I get as far as LaTeX compilation, then am stopped by the following error message.

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.406 #> -- ^^[
               [1mAttaching packages^^[[22m --------------------------------...

Error: LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.
>
```

This corresponds to the part of the R4DS book where we are shown how to load the tidyverse and, looking at the _main.tex file, I see many lines with what look like ANSI escape sequences starting on this line. They have the form ^[[1m, ^[[22m, and so on. I manually compiled the LaTeX output using lualatex and found that there are dozens if not hundreds of examples of this throughout the book. I suspected it was because I was using the `colorout` package in R, but it appears that that package is required, so others who are rendering successfully must be using it too. I believe I have successfully updated all relevant packages.

Comment: Why do you think `colorout` is required? I don't see any references to that in the R4DS source code. Those escapes do seem to be a problem and should not be used with latex output.

Comment: To answer your question, I thought `colorout` was required because, when I removed it from my `.Rprofile` file, I saw a message in the output saying "loading required package colorout". However, following your comment, I removed `colorout` again and saw no such message. However, I still get the ANSI escape codes. In RStudio, I chose Preferences > Console > Remove ANSI codes, but the ANSI codes are still in the output. If I could prevent the ANSI codes from being inserted, I believe the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I "solved" the problem by changing an option in the `_common.R` file from `crayon.enabled=TRUE` to `crayon.enabled=FALSE`. This removed the ANSI escape sequences from the book. Previously I had tried setting `options(crayon.enabled=FALSE)` in my R session, but this was evidently being overridden by the setting in `_common.R`.

**Update**: 23 Nov 2022
The process for rendering the files is completely different now because of the switch to Quarto. Here's how I did it.

```bash
Rscript -e 'update.packages()'
Rscript -e 'install.packages('quarto')'
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github("hadley/r4ds")
git clone https://github.com/hadley/r4ds.git
cd r4ds
```

Next, I wrote a small perl script to avoid the error messages I was getting about trying to render html material to pdf. (I'm omitting a lot of dead-ends I encountered in the process.)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Slurp qw(prepend_file);
my @files = glob( '*.qmd' );
my $header = "\n---\nprefer-html: true\n---\n\n";
foreach my $file (@files) {
  prepend_file($file, $header);
}
```

I ran the above script in the `r4ds` directory.

Next I loaded R and did the following:

```
library(quarto)
quarto_render("index.qmd", output_format = "pdf")
```

The above failed with the error message: "\begin{document} not found". Luckily, the aborted process leaves an index.tex file I can process and also gives a line number for the error. I went to that line number in the index.tex file and deleted the block of html I found there.

After that, I ran

```bash
lualatex index.tex
```

twice and got a successful render, minus the cover page. (You could presumably run `xelatex index.tex` instead.) There are a lot of problems with my render, such as the plots being too large to fit on the page. If I decide to spend time fixing them (unlikely, since Hadley seems to want us to use the online version) I'll modify this answer.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the `_quarto.yaml` you used to make the pdf?

Comment: I have unfortunately deleted all the relevant files long ago when Hadley said that pdf generation was a low priority. There are some advantages to pdf, so I tried again just now. It's completely different because of Quarto, so I amended my original answer to reflect the current process. Hope that helps!